# Knockout checked binding with no default

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am using Knockout to handle interactivity in a web app.  I am trying to create a multiple-choice quiz widget.  I want to present a question, and then a group of radio buttons which the user can pick from.  I do not want a default answer.

I have the following in my code:

```
 <!-- ko foreach: {data: answers, as: 'answer'} -->
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="radio" 
           name="answers" 
           data-bind="checkedValue: answer, checked: $parent.current.problem.response">
    <span data-bind="mathjax: answer.value.text">1.5</span>
  </li>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Now, the Knockout documentation says:

> When the user changes which radio button is selected, KO will set your model property to equal the value of the selected radio button. In the preceding example, clicking on the radio button with value="cherry" would set viewModel.spamFlavor to be "cherry".

So, based on the documentation, it is my understanding that the `current.problem.response` observable should be getting set to an `answer` object.  But instead, it is getting set to `on`.

I *think* this is because my `current.problem.response` observable is initially `null`.  This makes sense for my domain.  It should be empty if the user hasn't made a selection.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your scenario works. Maybe the problem is out of the scene.
This fiddle demonstrates it works http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/y3LpD/
Open console to see selected option.

Demo view model looks like

```
var vm = {
    answers: [
        { text: 'ans1' },
        { text: 'ans2' },
        { text: 'ans3' },
        { text: 'ans4' }
    ],
    response: ko.observable(null)
};

vm.answer = vm.answers[0];

vm.response.subscribe(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

The markup a little corrected according to the model

```
<!-- ko foreach: {data: answers, as: 'answer'} -->
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <input type="radio" 
           name="answers" 
      data-bind="checkedValue: answer, checked: $parent.response" />
    <span data-bind="text: answer.text"></span>
  </li>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Hope this can help. If you have any further problems, specify them in comments.

Comment: I see that it should work, but I don't understand why mine isn't working.  Instead of setting $parent.response to an answer, it's getting set to 'on'.  Bizarre.  Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: Could you change the fiddle to demonstate specifics of your case? I mean make it not working with your case. Stuff you've provided in the question looks pretty similar to what I put in the fiddle. I guess we'll find the problem this way.

Comment: I messed around with the fiddle and got it to look a lot more like mine (using ko.mapping was the biggest difference).  It was still working over there.  I noticed the fiddle was using ko 3.0.  My project was on 2.3.  I upgraded and it looks like it's working! :)

Comment: Great! It appeared to be outside of the case described. Glad that it's cleared )) I would really appreciate, if you mark the answer as applied ;)